# NoSuchMethodException - method's return type has changed - Want to accept both types

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jgroups, transitive-dependency

**Background**

I have a commons library that I have to update. This commons library has a third party dependency (jgroups) which was changed significantly in newer versions. Through transitive dependencies, the newer version of jgroups is sometimes required and this breaks the commons library.  I need to update some classes for compatibility with newer versions, while maintaining backwards compatibility.

**The Problem**

JGroups provides a `View` class, which has a method `getMembers()`.  In the old version (2.10.0), this method returns `Vector<Address>` and in the newer version (3.2.7), this returns `List<Address>`.  Any implementation of `java.util.Collection` will work for me, but the problem is I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodException`.  As I understand it, the `getMembers()` method found has the legacy `Vector<Address>` return type (based on the JGroups dependency in the commons library), but I am dragging in a newer JGroups version and that `View` class expects a `List<Address>` returned from the `getMembers()` method.

**Stacktrace**

I get the following error when starting up my application in Eclipse.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jgroups.View.getMembers()Ljava/util/Vector;
    at com.mycompany.commons.messaging.events.impl.distributed.JGroupsEventDistributionProvider$JGroupsEventReceiver.viewAccepted(JGroupsEventDistributionProvider.java:136) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.invokeCallback(JChannel.java:752) ~[jgroups-3.2.7.Final.jar:3.2.7.Final]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:710) ~[jgroups-3.2.7.Final.jar:3.2.7.Final]
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1020) ~[jgroups-3.2.7.Final.jar:3.2.7.Final]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.FLUSH.up(FLUSH.java:466) ~[jgroups-3.2.7.Final.jar:3.2.7.Final]
 ....
```

**Where it breaks**

```
Collection<Address> viewMembers = view.getMembers();
```

**Question**

Is it possible to support both versions, even though they are different implementations of `Collection`? How can I handle this scenario where I don't know the method return type until runtime?

Note:

I have tried to exclude the older version of JGroups that is being pulled in by adding an exclusion in my maven pom.  This has not worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>mycompany-commons-event-distributed-jgroups</artifactId>
        <!-- Note: JGroups dependency is provided by infinispan -->
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: More of a hack workaround than a solution - but what about providing your own utility method and calling `getMembersRaw()` instead. This returns the underlying array - so you will want to copy those values into a collection to prevent unintended modification. http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/View.html#getMembersRaw--

Comment: @deyur, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, getMembersRaw() is not available in my JGroups versions, 2.10.0 or 3.2.7

Comment: How about using reflection ? Field View.members is a Vector<Address> in 2.10.x and an Address[] array in 3.x. You could access field View.members and - depending on its type - return all members as a collection of addresses. Not nice, but should work...

Comment: @BelaBan Thanks for the recommendation!  It did work.  If you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using reflection ? Field View.members is a Vector in 2.10.x and an Address[] array in 3.x. You could access field View.members and - depending on its type - return all members as a collection of addresses. Not nice, but should work..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "plain java" for the app framework, I think you are generally out of luck.

Without using some sort of module framework such as OSGI, you only have a single pool of classes and every class loaded onto your classpath goes into that pool. This means you can't have multiple versions of the same JAR or the same class in your JVM at the same time.

Also, you must support multiple versions of the same JAR because you have at least two pieces of code compiled each against the different versions: one is expecting the return value of `Vector` and the other of `List`, so even if you could isolate the undesired one from your build environment, the code built against it would then not link to the proper binary and you will continue to get the runtime exception you see.

Unfortunately, you mentioned this is a "library" and not just a single app, which may make it even more difficult to apply a solution. Off the top of my head, I see these options for you moving forward, none of which are trivial and some may not be possible:

1. downgrade your code as necessary to only have a single version of jgroups in all dependency chains
2. rearchitect your app to use OSGI or a similar framework that supports multiple versions of the same library so dependency chains may diverge
3. rearchitect your app and fragment it into multiple that each run in their own JVM, communicating with sockets or any other means

For example, we have used the third option to split out a small portion of an app so it could depend on libraries with licenses unfriendly to our entire codebase but that portion could be licensed along with the library.

I am also not sure how the Java 9 module system would behave with this, but it might support multiple versions of the same module in the runtime simultaneously. If it's an option for you to use that beta or investigate, that may be worth your effort. However, you mentioned that the point was backward compatibility, so that may not be a viable option either.